# What's the highest-$n$ Rydberg state that's been created and detected experimentally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, rydberg-states

Rydberg states form an infinite series of electronic states that asymptotically approach the ionization potential of the atom or molecule, usually in good agreement with the simple Rydberg formula.

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/handle/1811/46079)</sup>

Experimentally, it seems that it's relatively workable to produce Rydberg states with principal quantum number $n$ up in the several hundreds. How high does this ladder go? That is, what is the highest $n$ that has been produced and detected in an experiment?

Similarly, what's the record in terms of circular Rydberg states, i.e. for Rydberg states with saturated angular momentum $\ell=n-1$?

Comment: Somewhat dated reference for n=32 is at https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.5508, with a focus on doing more than just making the state. The folks I know are more interested in the properties of the Rydberg states and what they can do with them rather than making the highest one possible...

Comment: @Jon sure and that's as it should be - there's little scientific value in pushing up the n for its own sake, and much more to be said in studying their properties and using them as tools for other stuff - but it's still nicgood to know how far up the ladder people go in that pursuit.

Comment: That said, I'm pretty sure I've seen papers with states in the few hundreds, but I can't find them at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a paper from 2009 in which they go up to $n=700$:

- Engineering atomic Rydberg states with pulsed electric fields. FB Dunning et al. [*J. Phys. B: At. Mol. Opt. Phys.* **42**, 022001 (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-4075/42/2/022001).

That's the highest I've ever come across. Targeting single Rydberg states spectroscopically becomes extremely difficult above the $n=100$-$200$ range because the spacing between levels becomes too small, scaling with $n^{-3}$ (not to mention that the levels themselves become extremely sensitive to external fields, scaling with $n^7$).

The highest state to which people can coherently excite is much lower. It is routinely done up to about $n=100$, sometimes a bit higher. In our lab we use $n=70$.